# Help Identifying SMD Microphone

Tags: identification, microphone

I suspect this component to be a SMD microphone made by ST. Unfortunately I could not map the writings on the device to any SMD microphone datasheet issued by ST.

Do you have a clue?

[image: SMD Microphone]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, it's this one:
http://www.st.com/web/catalog/sense_power/FM125/SC1564/PF251680

(It's the same one that's on the STM32F4 Discovery Kit)